# Why's the derivative of $f(x) = x^3-5x-2 $ not $3x^2-7$?

Tags: derivatives

I wanted to resolve this problem :
$$
f(x) = 3 x^2 - 5 x - 2
$$

to a derivative, and I did it like this :

[image: My work]

> $
> \begin{align}
> f(x) &= x^3-5x-2 \\
> f'(x) &= 3x^2-5-2 \\
>       &= 3x^2-7
> \end{align}
> $

but once I checked the correction, I found this:
$$
f'(x) = 3 x^2 - 5
$$

And I really don't know how they manage to get $3x^2 -5$ instead of $3x^2-7$.

Thanks for you time

Comment: To see why the derivative of a constant function is zero, you should think about the interpretation of the derivative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The derivative of a constant is zero, so if $$f(x) = x^3 - 5x - 2 = x^3 - 5 x^1 - 2,$$ the correct derivative is $$f'(x) = 3x^{3-1} - 5 \cdot 1 x^{1-1} - \color{red}{0} = 3x^2 - 5x^0 - 0 = 3x^2 - 5.$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, It helped me a lot !

Answer (score 4):

To take a derivative, recall the the operation on a polynomial is the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^n\right)=nx^{n-1},\tag{1}
\end{align}
meaning that in your problem, the derivative is this:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^3-5x-2\right)=3x^2-5.\tag{2}
\end{align}
Also, realize that a constant, such as "$-5$" has no rate of change, and therefore its derivative is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of a constant is zero. It was your mistake.

Comment: Could you explain the downvote?

Comment: Your other posts are nothing short of brilliant. This was my mistake. I up-voted another of your posts. My apologies.

Comment: @bd1251252, Ok. That's fine. :)